# Mounting applications of different paths with Istio

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

We have installed Istio on my Kubernetes cluster on AWS (we are using EKS). We have deployed several applications such as: Airflow, Jenkins, Grafana, etc. and we are able to reach them with `port-forward`. So, they are working as expected.

Now, what we would like to achieve is the possibility of mounting the applications on specific paths so that we can access them via an unique entrypoint.

Here an example to explain what I mean with "unique entrypoint":

- http://a517f7.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/aiflow/ and you can see Airflow dahsboard
- http://a517f7.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/jenkins/ and you can see Jenkins dahsboard
- http://a517f7.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/grafana/ and you can see Grafana dahsboard

What we tried is the following

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: apps-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: airflow-virtual-service  
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - apps-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /airflow
    route:
    - destination:
        host: webserver.airflow.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grafana-virtual-service  
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - apps-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /grafana
    route:
    - destination:
        host: grafana.grafana.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 3306
---
and so on
```

In this way but I keep having `Aiflow 404 = lots of circles` or similar depending on the service.

Do you know how to achieve such a result with Istio? We are also open to also use Nginx or Traefik.

Comment: your script looks good. Are you exposing `istio-ingressgateway` to Internet ? Can you print these info please `kubectl -n istio-system get services | grep istio-ingressgateway`

Comment: Yes, istio exposed a LB correctly `istio-ingressgateway     LoadBalancer   172.X.X.X    a517f2.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:31993/TCP,8060:31415/TCP,853:32575/TCP,15030:32215/TCP,15031:30523/TCP   1d`

Comment: Can you look at the log of `istio-ingressgateway` pod?? If loadbalancer it's correct it should log the requests to it.

Comment: I see the requests that are 404 because the path seems wrong. I made some changes in the `VirtualService` from `prefix: /airflow` to `prefix: /` for the Airflow service. In this case I am able to access the dashboard correctly. I think the reason is that the application is mounted on the `/` redirecting the requests towards the right endpoints. What I am trying to say is that applications have certain paths (`/users`, `/users/123` etc..) and what we want is to have `/application/users` and `/application/users/123`. So a Prefix basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on the comments:

The best way to expose a frontend & backend it's to separate both with a wildcard domain like `*.domain.com`.

For the frontend:

`my-app.domain.com/`

For the backend services it will always start with a subdomain like `api`:

`api.domain.com/foo`

For backend service you will need to use `rewrite` if your backend service it's no serving the path.

```
rewrite:
  uri: "/"
```

Check Istio docs for more info about rewrite https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#Destination

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but I already tried this road and I can't make it work :/ the `rewrite` will remove the `prefix` I put above. I do want to keep the prefix otherwise I cannot distinguish the applications.

Comment: @spaghettifunk without the rewrite the request will go to `webserver.airflow.svc.cluster.local/airflow` with the rewrite it should go to `webserver.airflow.svc.cluster.local/` does that service respond to the root path / ????

Comment: You are not losing the prefix /airflow /grafana path using rewrite. Rewrite will be use to comunícate with the services under kubernetes

Comment: indeed the service respond to the root path. In fact, for the `airflow` service, the `rewrite` works correctly but for other services I do have either a broken page (missing packages, lots of 404, etc.) or the old `Flower 404 = lots of circles`. Don't know what else to do.

Comment: But the other services on what path do they respond?

Comment: Can you add a example please of one that dont respond

Comment: I think that in general all the services they respond on the root path. Hence, I want them to be mounted on a specific path but still working. Regarding the services that don't respond are: Flower (part of Airflow), Grafana, Kiali, Jenkins, etc. Basically everything. Maybe it's not even possible what i want to do.

Comment: It should be posible. I have a similar structure as yours.

Comment: @spaghettifunk My structure for front and backend is to use a wildcard like for example `*.my-domain.cloud` so all my backends services goes to `api.my-domain.cloud/foo`, `api.my-domain.cloud/bar`, etc... and the frontend goes to `grafana.my-domain.cloud`, `kiali.my-domain.cloud`, etc.... With this schema your front will not have any issue

Comment: I just tried that way and it actually worked out. I think I had to do a combination of name routing and path routing and I obtained the result I wanted. Thanks @Victor Godoy. If you can edit the answer with the example you gave above, I'll mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @spaghettifunk ok!